# Best Fit Estimation for a scalar value

Tags: linear-algebra

What method should I use to obtain the best fit for $a$ which is a scalar value in the following equation:
$$a\textbf{z}=\textbf{b}$$
where $\textbf{z}$ and $\textbf{b}$ are vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
0 & = \totald{\,\verts{a\mathbf{z} - \mathbf{b}}^{2}}{a}
=\totald{}{a}\pars{a^{2}\mathbf{z}^{2} - 2a\mathbf{z}\cdot\mathbf{b} + b^{2}} = 2a\mathbf{z}^{2} - 2\mathbf{z}\cdot\mathbf{b}\quad\imp\quad
\color{#f00}{a} = \color{#f00}{\mathbf{z}\cdot\mathbf{b} \over \mathbf{z}^{2}}
\end{align}